# Request simple example of how to a TComplexMath class (source included)

Tags: delphi

I'm doing some Pascal programming using Borland Delphi7. I've download a fairly basic (and free) source code library of complex maths functions, but unfortunately it didn't come with any usage examples. As I'm not very familiar with classes in Pascal, I think I just need just one simple example of it's usage to get me started.

Anything will do, even an example of adding two numbers together will get me started. Here's what I've tried (very lame I know). I think my problem is that I don't know how to use the class constructor.

```
uses ComplexMath in 'complexmath.pas'

var z1,z2,z3 : TComplexNumber;
begin
  z1.R:=1.0; z1.I:=2.0;
  z2.R:=3.0; z2.I:=-1.0;
  z3 := TComplexMath.Add(z1,z2);
end.
```

Full source code for TComplexMath is available here: http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa070103a.htm. I've also cut and pasted a partial listing of the source code below (note that this code is the complete file except for where I've explicitly indicated it's been cut).

Partial TComplexMath source code listing is:

```
unit ComplexMath;

interface

uses Windows, SysUtils, Classes, Controls, Math;

type
  TComplexNumber = record
    R : single;
    I : single;
  end;

TComplexMath = class(TComponent)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;

    function Add(C1, C2 : TComplexNumber) : TComplexNumber; overload;
    { Returns the complex sum of C1 and C2 }

    function Add(C1, C2, C3 : TComplexNumber) : TComplexNumber; overload;
    { Returns the complex sum of C1 and C2 and C3 }

    ... and a bunch more like this ...

implementation

procedure Register;
  begin
    RegisterComponents('delphi.about.com', [TComplexMath]);
  end;

constructor TComplexMath.Create(AOwner : TComponent);
  begin
    inherited Create(AOwner);
  end;

 function TComplexMath.Add(C1, C2 : TComplexNumber) : TComplexNumber;
   begin
     Result.R := C1.R + C2.R;
     Result.I := C1.I + C2.I;
   end;

    ... and a bunch more like this ...

end.
```

After struggling for a while I eventually stripped out the class definition and used just the functions themselves (like a simple library of functions). And though this is working for me, I know it's not how this component was intended to be used. I'd really appreciate it if someone could show me a very simple example of using this class in the way it was intended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The intended usage is like this:

```
var
  cm: TComplexMath;

  z, w, sum: TComplexNumber;
begin

  cm := TComplexMath.Create(Self) // or nil, can most likely be anything
  try
    sum := cm.Add(z, w); // Now sum is the sum of z and w
  finally
    cm.Free;
  end;

end;
```

You could also create an instance of `TComplexMath` at application startup (or unit initialization, or something), and use that for the lifetime of your application:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

var
  cm: TComplexMath;

...

implementation

procedure Test;
begin

  sum := cm.Add(z, w); // Now sum is the sum of z and w

end;

...

initialization

  cm := TComplexMath.Create(nil);

finialization

  cm.Free;
```

Finally, since it is a component, you can drop it onto a form at design time. The instance will be called `ComplexMath1`, and you can use it in the form class, like

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  z, w, sum: TComplexNumber;    
begin
  sum := ComplexMath1.Add(z, w);
end;
```

I *really* dislike the design of this class. First, you'd ever only need one instance of it, so why not make the functions class functions instead? Really: why use a class at all? Finally, if you use a modern version of Delphi, you can use advanced records and operator overloading to make things like `z + w` work in your source code, just like `z` and `w` were simple types, like integers!

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I had a feeling that it would be something like that but I didn't figure out the "Self" parameter. Give me a few minutes to test this out and I'll give some more feedback. :)

Comment: cm := TComplexMath.Create(Nil) is working for me, but for some reason I can't use the parameter Self. It gives me the error "Undeclared Identifier: Self". Could this be because I'm only running it in a "console application" or have I left out something required in the "uses" clause?

Comment: @Stuart: `nil` also works. What is the 'owner'? Well, when the owner is freed, so are the things owned by it. `self` means the current instance of the class and exists only in methods. So, for instance, if you have a form and a button and double-click the button, you end up in a method like `procedure TForm1.Button1Click(...`, then `self` refers to the current instance of `TForm1`, probably `Form1`. But in this case, the owner isn't used for anything, so it doesn't really matter what you specify (unless you destroy it). So `nil` (meaning 'no owner') is perfectly fine.

Comment: So "self" isn't defined because I'm only a console application? {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

Comment: No, `Self` isn't available at the current line, because the current line isn't inside a method (=function or procedure belonging to a class, working with the current instance of it).

Comment: No, `Self` isn't defined because your code is not inside a method.

Comment: @Stuart - what you have done initially (strip everything class-related and using it as a library) seems the preferred approach in this case...

Comment: @Leonardo - Yes, that's basically what I've done. I've also modified it a bit and added some trig (and hyp-trig) functions.

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't use that code at all. It's really weak in my view. Here's something better:

```
type
  TComplex = record
  public
    class operator Implicit(const D: Double): TComplex;
    class operator Negative(const C: TComplex): TComplex;
    class operator Equal(const C1, C2: TComplex): Boolean;
    class operator NotEqual(const C1, C2: TComplex): Boolean;
    class operator Add(const C1, C2: TComplex): TComplex;
    class operator Add(const C: TComplex; const D: Double): TComplex;
    class operator Add(const D: Double; const C: TComplex): TComplex;
    class operator Subtract(const C1, C2: TComplex): TComplex;
    class operator Subtract(const C: TComplex; const D: Double): TComplex;
    class operator Subtract(const D: Double; const C: TComplex): TComplex;
    class operator Multiply(const C1, C2: TComplex): TComplex;
    class operator Multiply(const C: TComplex; const D: Double): TComplex;
    class operator Multiply(const D: Double; const C: TComplex): TComplex;
    class operator Divide(const C1, C2: TComplex): TComplex;
    class operator Divide(const C: TComplex; const D: Double): TComplex;
    class operator Divide(const D: Double; const C: TComplex): TComplex;
    function IsZero: Boolean;
    function IsNonZero: Boolean;
    function Conj: TComplex;
    function Sqr: TComplex;
    function Sqrt: TComplex;
    function Mag: Double;
    function SqrMag: Double;
  public
    r: Double;
    i: Double;
  end;

const
  ZeroComplex: TComplex = ();//initialise to zero;

class operator TComplex.Implicit(const D: Double): TComplex;
begin
  Result.r := D;
  Result.i := 0.0;
end;

class operator TComplex.Negative(const C: TComplex): TComplex;
begin
  Result.r := -C.r;
  Result.i := -C.i;
end;

class operator TComplex.Equal(const C1, C2: TComplex): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (C1.r=C2.r) and (C1.i=C2.i);
end;

class operator TComplex.NotEqual(const C1, C2: TComplex): Boolean;
begin
  Result := not (C1=C2);
end;

class operator TComplex.Add(const C1, C2: TComplex): TComplex;
begin
  Result.r := C1.r + C2.r;
  Result.i := C1.i + C2.i;
end;

class operator TComplex.Add(const C: TComplex; const D: Double): TComplex;
begin
  Result.r := C.r + D;
  Result.i := C.i;
end;

class operator TComplex.Add(const D: Double; const C: TComplex): TComplex;
begin
  Result.r := D + C.r;
  Result.i := C.i;
end;

class operator TComplex.Subtract(const C1, C2: TComplex): TComplex;
begin
  Result.r := C1.r - C2.r;
  Result.i := C1.i - C2.i;
end;

class operator TComplex.Subtract(const C: TComplex; const D: Double): TComplex;
begin
  Result.r := C.r - D;
  Result.i := C.i;
end;

class operator TComplex.Subtract(const D: Double; const C: TComplex): TComplex;
begin
  Result.r := D - C.r;
  Result.i := -C.i;
end;

class operator TComplex.Multiply(const C1, C2: TComplex): TComplex;
begin
  Result.r := C1.r*C2.r - C1.i*C2.i;
  Result.i := C1.r*C2.i + C1.i*C2.r;
end;

class operator TComplex.Multiply(const C: TComplex; const D: Double): TComplex;
begin
  Result.r := C.r*D;
  Result.i := C.i*D;
end;

class operator TComplex.Multiply(const D: Double; const C: TComplex): TComplex;
begin
  Result.r := D*C.r;
  Result.i := D*C.i;
end;

class operator TComplex.Divide(const C1, C2: TComplex): TComplex;
var
  R, Denominator: Double;
begin
  if abs(C2.r)>=abs(C2.i) then begin
    R := C2.i/C2.r;
    Denominator := C2.r+R*C2.i;
    Result.r := (C1.r+R*C1.i)/Denominator;
    Result.i := (C1.i-R*C1.r)/Denominator;
  end else begin
    R := C2.r/C2.i;
    Denominator := C2.i+R*C2.r;
    Result.r := (C1.r*R+C1.i)/Denominator;
    Result.i := (C1.i*R-C1.r)/Denominator;
  end;
end;

class operator TComplex.Divide(const C: TComplex; const D: Double): TComplex;
begin
  Result := C*(1.0/D);
end;

class operator TComplex.Divide(const D: Double; const C: TComplex): TComplex;
var
  R, Denominator: Double;
begin
  if abs(C.r)>=abs(C.i) then begin
    R := C.i/C.r;
    Denominator := C.r+R*C.i;
    Result.r := D/Denominator;
    Result.i := -R*Result.r;
  end else begin
    R := C.r/C.i;
    Denominator := C.i+R*C.r;
    Result.i := -D/Denominator;
    Result.r := -R*Result.i;
  end;
end;

function TComplex.IsZero: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Self=ZeroComplex;
end;

function TComplex.IsNonZero: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Self<>ZeroComplex;
end;

function TComplex.Conj: TComplex;
begin
  Result.r := r;
  Result.i := -i;
end;

function TComplex.Sqr: TComplex;
begin
  Result := Self*Self;
end;

function TComplex.Sqrt: TComplex;
var
  x, y, v, w: Double;
begin
  if IsZero then begin
    Result := ZeroComplex;
  end else begin
    x := abs(r);
    y := abs(i);
    if x>=y then begin
      v := y/x;
      w := System.Sqrt(x)*System.Sqrt(0.5*(1.0+System.Sqrt(1.0+v*v)));
    end else begin
      v := x/y;
      w := System.Sqrt(y)*System.Sqrt(0.5*(v+System.Sqrt(1.0+v*v)));
    end;
    if r>=0.0 then begin
      Result.r := w;
      Result.i := i/(2.0*w);
    end else begin
      if i>=0.0 then begin
        Result.i := w;
      end else begin
        Result.i := -w;
      end;
      Result.r := i/(2.0*Result.i);
    end;
  end;
end;

function TComplex.Mag: Double;
var
  x, y, Temp: Double;
begin
  x := abs(r);
  y := abs(i);
  if x=0.0 then begin
    Result := y;
  end else if y=0.0 then begin
    Result := x;
  end else if x>y then begin
    Temp := y/x;
    Result := x*System.Sqrt(1.0+Temp*Temp);
  end else begin
    Temp := x/y;
    Result := y*System.Sqrt(1.0+Temp*Temp);
  end;
end;

function TComplex.SqrMag: Double;
begin
  Result := System.Sqr(r) + System.Sqr(i);
end;
```

This uses operator overloading to implement the `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` operators. You will find the code that you can write based on this `TComplex` record to be much more expressive than the component you refer to in the question.

There is more functionality implemented in the code that you have linked to. However, it's easy to extend the record in this answer to add more functionality.

Of course, since you have Delphi 7, the code in this answer is of no help to you. That's because operator overloading wasn't introduced until later. If you are going to do any serious mathematics you need operator overloading to make your code readable.

Comment: +1. I was just about to update my answer with a link to your `TVector2D` record. Now I guess I don't have to! Of course, *this* is how it should look like! Forget about the code at About.com.

Comment: @LURD The first thing I did after upgrading from D6 to D2010 was convert all my maths code (and there is a lot of it) to op. overloaded records like this. It made an enormous difference to the readability of our code.

Comment: Indeed, I really love this particular kind of syntactic sugar.

Comment: Yes, made the same journey myself.

Comment: The thing that's missing is templates so that we can write algorithms without having to fix the underlying data type.

Comment: Thanks very much David. I'm testing it out now.

Comment: @Stuart, this kind of advanced records was introduced in Delphi-2006.

Comment: Yes, @Stuart, this won't work in D7. But I couldn't resist posting this. It will be useful for anyone with modern Delphi. Even you should abandon that pointless class. No need to use a class there. Just have some functions that operate on the record.

Comment: Yes, when I could figure out how to call the constructor I ended up just striping out the class stuff and using it as a basic library of functions. Now I realize that I wasn't missing anything. :)

Comment: Will this code work with the free Codeware Delphi compiler? I've got a copy of the Codeware compiler but I've never installed it.

Comment: They don't do a free version any more.

Comment: I download "Codegear Delphi 2006" ages ago when they were offering it for free. I've never installed it but I do have the both the installer and the "registration" file. Would the above code work with this compiler?

Comment: Excellent. I've finally got a reason to install it. :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Why do you call the imaginary part `c`? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Andreas That record started life before my time. I expect the c is for complex which is indeed rather odd.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand There, is that more to your liking?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Although, now I'm not so sure. Isn't `i` a bad choice? That symbol already has special meaning in complex arithmetic.

Comment: @David: I know. Personally, I'd go for `a` and `b`, since we are all very familiar with *a* + *bi*. (One could also consider `Re` and `Im`, although there is a major objection against these, since I consider `Re` and `Im` to be *maps* \C -> \R.)