# Delphi 2006 wont allow const parameters of type record within record method?

Tags: delphi

### **UPDATE:**  Simple workaround. Data fields before Method/Operator fields.

Today I tried to reproduce this bug using the simplest example I could make.

- I started with a basic record (TBasicRecord) having only simple set and print methods (no operators), and there was no problem passing const x:TBasicBecord.
- I then added a unary operator thinking that would trigger the bug, but still no problems in passing the record as const.
- I then added a binary operator, but and still the bug wouldn't surface.
- Finally I noticed in my simple example I had declared the data fields ahead of the method fields, and this turned out to be all that's required to mute the bug.

I'd also made my data fields private, so at first I thought that must be the issue, but in the end it turned out to be irrelevant. The only thing that makes a difference is whether of not I placed the data fields before the operator and method fields.

Overall I'm happy with this resolution. Personally I've always put the data fields first anyway. It's funny that doing it the other way around didn't seem to cause any other problems, just as long as you don't try to pass the record type as a "const" parameter anywhere.

---

**Original Posting:**

Previously I have been using Delphi 7 but today installed Delphi 2006 to gain access to operator methods that D7 didn't support.

I was attempting to compile the code (complex number implementation) listed in one of the replies to an earlier question here: [Request simple example of how to a TComplexMath class (source included)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074316/request-simple-example-of-how-to-a-tcomplexmath-class-source-included/15074443#15074443)

Here's a partial listing of the relevant code:

```
type
  TComplex = record
  public
    class operator Implicit(const D: Double): TComplex;
    class operator Negative(const C: TComplex): TComplex;
    class operator Equal(const C1, C2: TComplex): Boolean;
    class operator NotEqual(const C1, C2: TComplex): Boolean;
    class operator Add(const C1, C2: TComplex): TComplex;
    class operator Add(const C: TComplex; const D: Double): TComplex;
    class operator Add(const D: Double; const C: TComplex): TComplex;
    class operator Subtract(const C1, C2: TComplex): TComplex;
    class operator Subtract(const C: TComplex; const D: Double): TComplex;
    class operator Subtract(const D: Double; const C: TComplex): TComplex;
    class operator Multiply(const C1, C2: TComplex): TComplex;
    class operator Multiply(const C: TComplex; const D: Double): TComplex;
    class operator Multiply(const D: Double; const C: TComplex): TComplex;
    class operator Divide(const C1, C2: TComplex): TComplex;
    class operator Divide(const C: TComplex; const D: Double): TComplex;
    class operator Divide(const D: Double; const C: TComplex): TComplex;
    function IsZero: Boolean;
    function IsNonZero: Boolean;
    function Conj: TComplex;
    function Sqr: TComplex;
    function Sqrt: TComplex;
    function Mag: Double;
    function SqrMag: Double;
  public
    r: Double;
    c: Double;
  end;

class operator TComplex.Negative(const C: TComplex): TComplex;
begin
  Result.r := -C.r;
  Result.c := -C.c;
end;
---- etc ---
```

The problem is, when I try to compile this code (in D2006), **every** operator that takes a TComplex type gives an error of E2037: Declaration of "----" differs from the previous declaration. (where "---" is the operator name).

My work around was to just remove the **const** keyword from every TComplex parameter and then the code complies (and runs) correctly. I can keep the "const x: Double" parameters,the compiler gives no error on those, but I had to remove "const" from all of the others.

Does anyone know if this is some compiler option that's not enabled? Or is this something supported in later versions of Delphi but not D2006? Or just me doing something else incorrectly?

Also, if I cant use const parameters here, would there be any advantage to just substituting **var** for **const** (compared to just deleting the const keyword altogether).

Comment: That looks like a compiler bug. I'd avoid using var. How would that help?

Comment: As for the var/const change, you can easily try it. @David the var and const parameters are passed by reference, thus no copy of the parameter is performed to the stack. IMHO that's faster and cleaner. If the compiler accepts a var parameter I would use it rather than a parameter passed by value.

Comment: @jachguate: I really disagree. `var` forces the argument to be a variable, for one thing...

Comment: @jachguate But then the function can modify it. So pass by value is semantically better than by variable reference. Knowing the back story here, and being the author of the code in question, I disagree with you.

Comment: Yes indeed. "var" is more risky as there is no compiler check that nothing is modified. Given that the variables aren't being modified, I was wondering if there was any efficiency advantage to using "var".

Comment: @Stuary: It is more than that. In a normal argument (`function test(a: integer): integer`) you can change `a`, without changing the variable passed as argument.

Comment: @Andreas. Yes I totally understand that. Given that the routines aren't assigning anything to these "const" variables however, I though that using was "var" feasible.

Comment: I'd actually be surprised and disappointed if you could use var for an operator. I'd also hope the compiler wrote efficient code for passs by value.

Comment: @David I'm not advising the usage, maybe I didn't express it correctly. I know it changes the semantics and as a general rule you don't change const by var just for the sake of doing it.

I tested the code in D2007 and it takes the const parameters. I have no D2006 at hand to check by myself.

Comment: @David you can. I just changed the const for a var and it compiles. Let me play 5 min with that toy) :D

Comment: @David. When it passes a "TComplex" by value, does it only have to pass the data fields (double: r,c), or is there overhead from the methods as well?

Comment: @Stuart: I think you have forgotten the 'first point' in my example below.

Comment: That sucks! Does that mean I can write a := b+c and have all three variables modified? Boo hiss!

Comment: @David, you can. I just made it happen and the b and c variables are in fact, modified after `a := b + c`;

Comment: While this is a complete aside, I really like Math387 for handling complex numbers.  It's a free download for Delphi from DewResearch and it is really fast (as far as x87 asm code goes).  I've done a few specific algorithms a bit quicker with SSE assembly where the 80-bit precision isn't as critical but it's otherwise a really good library if you need to do serious complex math.  I've compiled with it up to XE2 with no issues. http://www.dewresearch.com/downloads-site/132-download-area-delphi  -- ref http://www.dewresearch.com/help/delphi/mtxvec/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=Math387.html

Comment: @J... When is 80 bit precision is ever critical?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan put math and physics together and often it becomes so.  At the moment I'm doing numerical optimization (quasi-Newton - large scale problems) on very sensitive optical systems.  When you start hitting higer order derivatives with very small step sizes the extra precision really makes a difference, at least in terms of how far out you can reach with an algorithm, before it starts to break apart into nonsense.

Comment: @J... I've always found that a re-think of the algo is what's needed when double precision is not enough.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan perhaps... sometimes reality is a tough mistress.  I can't re-write the laws of physics, and if I need a difference in the numerical gradient of a twice differentiated physical quantity (not easily reconstructed otherwise) and haven't yet beaten Goldfarb or Shanno in finding a fast n>1000 dimensional problem space minimization scheme I find it's just as well to stick with the higher precision and get an answer that works.  As with all such things, new algorithms are easier to imagine than to implement, especially with extremely complex problems.

Comment: @J... often an expression can be re-expressed to avoid the problems, but may be not yours

Comment: Why move from Delphi 7 to 2006 in the year 2013?  XE3,XE2,and XE are all great versions.  If you MUST move from 7 up to a non-unicode version at least move to 2007. 2006 and 2005 are terrible versions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know what you mean.  Such are complex problems, however, and beyond the scope of any discussion we could hope to have here  ;)  I respect and understand the point you are making - I just know that I've switched from x87 extended to SSE code for *some* operations and the loss of precision has led to error accumulation that led to a detriment in ultimate performance.  When it means the difference between being able to solve a problem and manufacture a solution, I'll take the 80 bits...at least for the moment.

Comment: @WarrenP: If XE2 is such a great version, why does it crash or hang 6 times a day on average?

Comment: @Warren re: Why move from Delphi 7 to 2006 in the year 2013? Only because it's a version that I have on hand. I've got registered copies of Delphi2 (which I actually bought way back when) and Delphi7 and Delphi 2006, with the latter two being downloaded for free. Since I only write occasional code for non-professional purposes I didn't want to buy any new products at this time.

Comment: @Marjan Mine doesn't. XE3 is better than XE2. Are you forgetting how bad 2005 and 2006 were. They were dire. Truly dire.

Comment: Never had problems with D2006! D2009 was good as well. D2010 offered a number of usability and debugging improvements, but started the destabilization of the IDE, possibly related to generics. We skipped XE and went straight for XE2 as we badly needed the 64 bit compiler. It has proven an agony. The 64 bit debugger is, well, buggy to be polite. The IDE and/or the background compilation isn't much better. XE2sp3 regularly produces all sorts of internal errors in the messages windows and/or trots off on a journey to a stack overflow, increasing memory use by 16Mb per tick...

Comment: Oh and XE3 isn't an option, nor is XE2sp4 => they barf on our code base. We are hoping XE4 might show some improvement but aren't holding our breath.

Comment: Delphi 2006 had a number of bugs related to operator overloading, and this was one of them. It got fixed in Delphi 2007.

Comment: You people need to call Oprah, get your own TV network talk show. :P

Comment: Stuart: You would probably enjoy using the "Starter Edition" of XE3, it's quite inexpensive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should *not* replace `const` by `var`. Let me explain why.

## Background

```
function Add(a: integer): integer;
begin
  result := a + 5;
end;
```

returns its argument + 5. Try `ShowMessage(IntToStr(Add(10)))`. You can also do `a := 10; ShowMessage(IntToStr(Add(a)))` to get the same result. In both cases, the thing passed to the function `Add` is the number `10`.The message shows `15`.

The intended use of `var` parameters is like this:

```
procedure Add(var a: integer);
begin
  a := a + 5;
end;
```

`var` indicates that the argument variable should be passed by reference; that is, only a pointer to the argument variable should be passed to the procedure/function.

Hence, now you can do

```
a := 10;
Add(a);
ShowMessage(IntToStr(a)); // You get 15
```

Now you *cannot* even do `Add(10)`, since `10` isn't a variable at all!

To compare,

```
function Add(a: integer): integer;
begin
  a := a + 5;
  result := a;
end;
```

will not affect `a`. So,

```
a := 10;
ShowMessage(IntToStr(Add(a))); // You get 15
ShowMessage(IntToStr(a)); // You get 10
```

Now, consider this horrible function:

```
function Add(var a: integer): integer;
begin
  a := a + 5;
  result := a;
end;
```

This will also return its argument + 5, but it will also affect its argument (very unexpextedly!!), and you cannot pass anything but variables as arguments (so `Add(10)` won't work!!)!

```
a := 10;
ShowMessage(IntToStr(Add(a))); // You get 15
ShowMessage(IntToStr(a)); // You get 15 (!!!)
```

So, what is `const`? Well, `const` roughly means "pass by reference if possible (to speed up; for instance, you need not make a copy of a large record), but do never accept any changes to the argument". Hence, a `const` argument effectively works as normal argument except that you cannot change it:

```
function Add(const a: integer): integer;
begin
  result := a + 5;
end;
```

works while

```
function Add(const a: integer): integer;
begin
  a := a + 5;
  result := a;
end;
```

doesn't even compile! But you can still do `Add(10)`.

## The Relevant Case

From this discussion, it should be clear that you shouldn't replace `const` by `var`. Indeed,

1. If you change from `const` to `var`, your functions no longer accept arguments that are literals (`10`) or expressions (`Tag + 30` or `SomeFunc(a, b)`). **This is a major show-stopper!**
2. Future implementations of the functions might change the arguments, which will accidently change the variables passed as arguments.

**Example of first point.** Using `const` or normal arguments:

```
function Complex(a, b: real): TComplex;
begin
  result.r := a;
  result.c := b;
end;

...

var
  c, d: TComplex;
begin    
  d := -c;                        // Works!
  d := -Complex(10, 20);          // Works!
```

But using `var`:

```
var
  c, d: TComplex;
begin    
  d := -c;                        // Works!
  d := -Complex(10, 20);          // [DCC Error] Unit5.pas(262):
                                  // E2015 Operator not applicable to this
                                  // operand type
```

This will not work either (with `var`):

```
var
  a, b, c: TComplex;
begin

  a := -(b + c);
```

Indeed, now the argument of `Negative` isn't a variable, but the expression `b + c`. So you lose very much!

**Example of second point.** Say you have a bad day and you suckify the implementation of `Negative` to

```
class operator TComplex.Negative(var C: TComplex): TComplex;
begin
  C.r := -C.r;
  C.c := -C.c;
  result := C;
end;
```

then the following code,

```
var
  c, d: TComplex;
begin

  c := Complex(10, 20);
  d := -c;

  ShowMessage(FloatToStr(c.r));
  ShowMessage(FloatToStr(d.r));
```

which used to result in messages `10` and `-10`, will suddenly change and yield `-10`, `-10`, which is highly unexpected!

## Conclusion

The solution in your case, therefore, is simply to remove `const` altogether (and NOT replace it by `var`!).

Comment: Thanks Andreas. Yes I understand the side effect example shown in the "suckified" Negative implementation above. I understand that you need to be very careful using var parameters for "in" variables.

Comment: Interestingly when I tested the other problem (of passing immediate values to a function using "var" variables),  I didn't get any errors when doing this with the operators (even though doing the same thing in a function does cause an error). I'm not sure why that is. Anyway, in this case the **only** variables for which const isn't compiling are the TComplex Record types, so the point about immediate parameters wont effect me.

Comment: @Stuart: Yes, it will. I even gave an example of that. (Well, maybe not 'record literals', but still record-valued *expressions*.) Anyhow, I blew up parts of my brain writing this overly long answer, so I need to go to sleep now! (Regarding the other thing, it shouldn't be possible to pass literals or expressions as a `var` parameter. If it is in Delphi 2006, and you start relying on it, you will get unpleasant surprises when you upgrade...)

Comment: Yes that's right, you definitely cant pass literals to a var parameter in either a function or procedure, but for some reason it didn't cause any problem with the operators. I tested it with "Operator Add(C: TComplex, var D:Double):TComplex" and amazingly z2 := z1+1.0 still complied and ran correctly. Anyway that's definitely an oddity, I did this just for a test and have no intention of doing this with the double types.

Comment: @Stuart: Your analysis is incorrect. In your example, `Add(TComplex, double)` isn't run at all! It can't be! But what is run, instead? Well, this one: `Add(TComplex, TComplex)` where the second argument is upgraded from double to complex via `Implicit(double)`!

Comment: Sorry about being a bit slow to digest all that Andreas. Many valid points but none appeared to be show stoppers until I tested "a := -(b + c). Yes indeed the failure to be able to chain operators like this is a complete fail for the "var" option. Thanks for pointing that one out.

Comment: "second argument is upgraded from double to complex via Implicit(double)". That's interesting, I didn't realize that. So may I ask then, what is the point of including the Add(C:TComplex; D:Double) form of the operator. Is this routine never actually called?

Comment: @Stuart: Good point. It certainly seems somewhat superfluous. But I just tried, and the compiler choses `Add(TComplex, double)` before `Add(TComplex, TComplex)` if it can (that is, no `var` if the argument is a literal!). If `Add(TComplex, double)` is impossible, like in your example, it goes for the next possible match. So in theory you could produce 'record arithmetics' that is highly unpredictable by making two possible 'approaches' (like these two) produce different results!

Comment: @Stuart, you can omit them if you like. Code will be a bit slower though.

Comment: @LU RD. I have no choice other than to omit the "const" paramaters (for all of the TComplex parameters). Delphi 2006 simply refuses to compile the code otherwise.

Comment: @Stuart: I believe LU RD was talking about `Add(C:TComplex; D:Double) `, not the `const`! :)

Comment: @Stuart, code is more efficient when not having to use the implicit roundtrip.

Comment: "if is impossible, like in your example, it goes for the next possible match". Ok that's good. In this case then it's definitely not superfluous, because many of the implementations can be made much more efficient if one of the parameters is known to be real. I've already written my own fairly comprehensive complex library including many other functions such as all trig,  hyp-trig and their inverses. I was able to make many of the implementations faster and more efficient for the one real parameter case.

Comment: Andreas: you said, "Now you cannot even do Add(10), since 10 isn't a variable at all!"  Sorry for the diversion, but in 1971, the IBM Fortran compiler erroneously allowed Add(10). After the call, a ShowMessage(10) would display 15.  Now THAT'S a bug!

Comment: @Frank. Yep that's a doozy. It's interesting that as Pascal programmers we may worry about the danger of possible side effects from using "var" parameters in a just a few lines of code, while Fortran programmers must go a whole lifetime without using anything else. :p

Answer (score 6):

Don't replace const with var in operator overloads. Period.

Even if you promise to never modify the var param inside the bodies of your functions (a dubious basis to begin with), just the presence of var params will destroy a very important aspect of operator functions: composition of expressions. A var param in an operator function makes it impossible to compose that operator together with other operators in compound expressions, because function results cannot be passed into var params.

Example: `(A + B) * C`.

If A, B, and C are all TComplex type, then this compiles down to `TComplex.Multiply(TComplex.Add(A, B), C)`.  If TComplex.Multiply is declared with var params, the function result of Add cannot be passed into Multiply (because a function result is an intermediate value, not a variable that lives at a specific memory address), which means a simple math expression like (A + B) * C will not compile.

So, if you want your operators to be usable in compound expressions, don't use var params in your operator functions.

Comment: Thanks dthorpe. Yes, of all the points made previously by Andreas, that was indeed the most compelling.