# Is there any convention for data fields coming before or after the methods? (In Class or Object or Record)

Tags: delphi

When you define a Class (or an Object or Record with methods), I was just wondering if there's any convention as to whether the data fields should appear before the method fields?

I mean like the difference between the two cases in the following trivial example. (*edited* to make the specific problem clearer)

```
type TWhatever = Object
      private
        a,b : Integer;
      public
        procedure SetWhatever(x,y :Integer);
        procedure ShowWhatever;
      end;
```

versus

```
type TWhatever = Object
      public
        procedure SetWhatever(x,y :Integer);
        procedure ShowWhatever
      private
        a,b : Integer;
     end;
```

I've always used the convention of listing the data fields first, but to be honest I didn't really think it made any difference. Recently however I came across some code that didn't work (wouldn't compile) unless the data fields were listed first.

I've documented the case here: [Delphi 2006 wont allow const parameters of type record within record method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145615/delphi-2006-wont-allow-const-parameters-of-type-record-within-record-method)

The summary is that if you put the data fields after the methods, then the code wont compile if the object has any methods that try to pass the given object as "const" parameter. For example something like this won't compile:

```
procedure TWhatever.SomeMethod( const : w1: TWhatever);
```

Apparently it will compile on later versions of Delphi, but I've tested it on both Delphi7 and Delphi 2006 and it wont compile on either.

The problem only appears if you do **all three** things (data fields last, pass object as parameter in method, use the const keyword for this parameter). So you can solve the problem by either removing the const keyword from the parameter or by putting the data fields ahead of the methods.

Anyway, this issue has just made me wonder if there is a convention to be followed here?

**EDITED I added this to give a specific code example**

The following program fails to compile on both D7 and D2006:

```
program bugtest;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses SysUtils;

type Tob = object
   public
    procedure setOb(const a,b: integer);
    procedure addToOb(const ob1: Tob);
    procedure printOb;
   private
    x,y : Integer;
   end;

procedure Tob.setOb(const a,b: integer);
begin
  x:=a; y:=b;
end;

procedure Tob.addToOb(const ob1: Tob);
begin
  x:=x+ob1.x; y:= y+ob1.y;
end;

procedure Tob.printOb;
begin
  writeln(x,' ',y);
end;

var r1,r2: Tob;
begin
  r1.setOb(2,3);
  r2.setOb(10,100);
  r1.addToOb(r2);
  r1.printOb;
  r2.printOb;
  readln;
end.
```

The following program compiles and runs perfectly on both D7 and D2006:

```
program bugtest;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses SysUtils;

type Tob = object
   private
    x,y : Integer;
   public
    procedure setOb(const a,b: integer);
    procedure addToOb(const ob1: Tob);
    procedure printOb;
   end;

procedure Tob.setOb(const a,b: integer);
begin
  x:=a; y:=b;
end;

procedure Tob.addToOb(const ob1: Tob);
begin
  x:=x+ob1.x; y:= y+ob1.y;
end;

procedure Tob.printOb;
begin
  writeln(x,' ',y);
end;

var r1,r2: Tob;
begin
  r1.setOb(2,3);
  r2.setOb(10,100);
  r1.addToOb(r2);
  r1.printOb;
  r2.printOb;
  readln;
end.
```

Delphi 7 version is: **Delphi Personal Version 7.0 build 4.453**.

D2006 version is: **Borland Delphi for MS Windows. Version 10.0.2288.42451, Update2**.

[image: Screenshot of compiler]

Comment: How did you get, that it's not possible to define method which uses the class itself as a parameter ? That's what works...

Comment: To be honest I haven't tried it for the "class" type, but it's definitely not a problem doing this with either the **object** type or the **record** (with methods) type. Note that records with methods is only in D2006 onward.

Comment: Using just defined **record** or **object** type itself as a certain parameter type of a method compiles without a problem in Delphi 2009.

Comment: If I am not wrong the original Pascal required that `var` clause should precede all procedure&function declarations in every code block.

Comment: Yes that right. Before the first begin statement in any function or procedure and same in the main program.

Comment: There's probably a convention to put the fields before the methods. In other languages the convention would be reversed. You can do it however you please. In your case there's obviously a benefit from swapping it round from the way I wrote it. I wanted to put the operators first.

Comment: Thanks David. At least I've found a good work around. I found this by trying to write the smallest amount of code to reproduce the bug I was getting with the TComplex unit. I just couldn't reproduce it until I noticed that I'd changed the order in which the data/method fields were defined.

Comment: It's interesting. Strange bug it seems. Long since fixed though. Too bad you can't use a modern Delphi. I hope you enjoy adding functionality to my TComplex!

Comment: Yes thanks David. I'd already written a complex library and added a lot of code for scientific functions. It worked well, but without the operator capabilities of the newer record type it made for pretty poor readability. Your code showed me how to add the operator functionality which has helped a lot. Just trying to trace this bug has bothered me, but the workaround turned out not too bad. I'm not having any other issues with D2006, it seems stable enough and it's got what I want in the newer record type. :)

Comment: Your *specific example* does not compile in D2007, DXE or DXE2 either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's fair to say that there is a widely used convention. Typically a class declaration would be arranged like this:

```
TMyClass = class
  // published declarations, managed by form designer
  Component1: TMyComponent;
  procedure MyEventHandler(Sender: TObject);
private
  FMyPrivateField: Integer;
  procedure MyPrivateMethod;
protected
  FMyProtectedField: Integer;
  procedure MyProtectedMethod;
public
  FMyPublicField: Integer;
  procedure MyPublicMethod;
published
  FMyPublishedField: Integer;
  procedure MyPublishedMethod;
end;
```

In other words the sections would be organised with the form designer's declarations first, and then in order of increasing visibility.

Interestingly other conventions are used in other languages. For example, take a look at the [Google C++ style guidelines](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Declaration_Order#Declaration_Order) where the order of sections is the reverse of the above.

Personally I would prefer to see the public declarations first. When reading code that already exists I am typically reading with a top-down perspective. And often when writing code, I find that a top-down approach is beneficial.

Looking at my `TComplex` record, there is a reason why the declarations are ordered as they are. I have a number of such similar records and some of them are variant records. For example:

```
type
  TVector = record
  public
    class operator Negative(const V: TVector): TVector;
    class operator Equal(const V1, V2: TVector): Boolean;
    class operator NotEqual(const V1, V2: TVector): Boolean;
    class operator Add(const V1, V2: TVector): TVector;
    class operator Subtract(const V1, V2: TVector): TVector;
    class operator Multiply(const V: TVector; const D: Double): TVector;
    class operator Multiply(const D: Double; const V: TVector): TVector;
    class operator Divide(const V: TVector; const D: Double): TVector;
    function IsZero: Boolean;
    function IsNonZero: Boolean;
    function IsUnit: Boolean;
    function Max: Double;
    function Sum: Double;
    function Mag: Double;
    function SqrMag: Double;
    function MagNormalComponent: Double;
    procedure MakeAxisymmetric;
    class function SNaN: TVector; static;
    function GetHashCode: Integer; inline;
  public
    case Boolean of
    False:
      (X, Y, Z: Double);
    True:
      (a: array [1..3] of Double);
  end;
```

Now, the variant part of the record must appear last. It is a compilation error to do otherwise. And so there's simply no choice for this record. Having established the convention for `TVector` and related records, `TComplex` simply followed suit.

Comment: Thanks David. This answered a very important doubt that I had regarding whether or not this work around was always applicable. Your example of the variant fields shows that in some circumstances it's not an option to just shift the data fields ahead of the methods. Of course you could always embed another record structure to handle that but it obviously makes the code more messy.

Comment: Exactly. Embedding a record allows you to work around it at the expense of readability.

Comment: BTW. I think I've got a hunch on how this bug is operating. As you know, the "const" keyword gives the compiler the option of choosing the parameter passing method based on it's own optimization criteria. I think that what's happening is that when the compiler strikes the methods with the const parameters before it's encountered the data fields, it makes a decision right there as to how it will treat those parameters. Later however, after the data fields have been encountered, it "changes its mind" about how it wants to pass this object. (...continued...)

Comment: So now when it reaches the actual method implementation, it's internally got some kind of conflicting representation of how that those parameters should be treated (compared to in the prototype), so it gives the error of "... differs from previous definition", even though they are actually written identically.

Comment: Yes, it's going to be something along those lines.

Comment: Yes, and as a bit of evidence of this I expanded my trivial example above so that the data fields contained three integers (only). I then tested placing some of the integers ahead of the methods, and some afterward. With a single integer defined before the methods and the other two afterwards it was not enough to alter its behavior (error still occurred). However with two integers defined before the method and the third defined at the end, it altered it's behavior and suppressed the error. Clearly the two integer (8 byte) data load was enough sway it as to how it would pass this object.

Answer (score 4):

As per the compiler, **fields declarations goes before any method declaration in any [class section](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Private,_Protected,_Public,_and_Published_Declarations)**. There may be any number of sections on a class, even with the same visibility.

For example:

```
type
  TMyObject = class
  private
    FTest: Integer;
    procedure A();
  private
    FOtherTest: Integer;
    procedure B();
  end;
```

compiles and you can argue if `FOtherTest` is after `procedure A()` or not.

As this is enforced by the compiler, there's no way to make it other way, so I'm not sure if call it a *convention*, but it have to be that way.

On the other hand,

```
type
  TMyObject = class
  private
    procedure A();
    FTest: Integer;
  end;
```

doesn't compile, with the error:

> E2169 Field definition not allowed after methods or properties

It doesn't matter if you pass it as any type of parameter. In my experience, the error is emmited if you just declare any field after a method.

#### Edit

After the question was edited, the OP says a **object** (different than a class) doesn't compile in Delphi 7 or 2006 if a Field is declared in a different section after a section having methods, if the object passed as a const parameter to a routine.

I managed to run my *very old* D7 in a VM and this example compiles OK:

[image]

It compiles with a `object` or `class` declaration, and since `records` didn't support methods on that version, obviously a record declaration doesn't compile.

#### Edit2

It also compiles if the object is passed as a const parameter to a method (regardless if is a method of the same object or other)

[image]

Comment: Thanks jachguate. That's handy to know, but unfortunately that wasn't my specific problem. Sorry but when I typed the above simple examples I edited out the "public" and "private" keywords for the sake of brevity (thinking that it didn't really effect the question). I've edited the question to truly represent the "bug". As it now shows, I get this issue even if the data and the methods are in different sections.

Comment: So what about if the methods and data are NOT in the same class section?

Comment: @Stuart your edit makes that a very different question. Since D2007 is the oldest Delphi I have at hand, I really can't tell you about previous versions, but in 2007 it compiles OK.

Comment: Yes it compiles both ways in D7 and D2006 too. It's just that if you do it the second way (data section after method section) then you get this obscure bug where everything seems to work totally normally *except* for "const parameters" of the object type.

Comment: It compiles in 2007 with the const parameter for class, object and record. Since I never used old fashion objects after Turbo Pascal, I'm not sure why are you trying to use object anyway, since with a Class I'm pretty sure it also compiles in any Delphi version.

Comment: Actually it was the newer Record (with methods) type that I was originally using when I struck this issue (re the TComplex code from the link in the question). I only changed it from type "Record" to "Object" so that I could test for the bug in D7 (which doesn't support the newer Record type). The behavior is identical for object and record in D2006.

Comment: Anyway, what do you think about the practice of always placing the data fields first (even if they are in their own "class section", private or public etc). It appears that, in some circumstances, this is necessary for these older versions of Delphi. It doesn't seem like such a bad restriction to me. I can't think of any circumstances where requiring this "order" would cause any difficulty?

Comment: @Stuart I managed to run my old computer in the VM with D7 and it compiles with a Object declaration, but not with a record, since records doesn't support methods in that version. Are you sure of what you're stating?

Comment: When you say "it", are you referring to the simple example code I posted in the opening question, or the TComplex code I linked. Yes there is no problems with the above simple code either way. The problem only arises if you try to add a method that passes the object as a "const" parameter.

Comment: "it compiles with a Object declaration, but not with a record, since records doesn't support methods in that version" Yes that's correct, that's what I stated. I was talking about the more subtle problem that if you do it the second way (data section last) then it won't let you have have methods that pass the object as a "const" parameter.

Comment: Ok thanks, I see what you've done now. Look this is a very specific error/bug. It only happens if the object (or record in the case of D2006) has methods (part of the object/record) that try to pass the object/record as a const parameter. You don't get the problem in the above example because procedure "Test" is not a method in TMyobject.

Comment: In fact now I've added `procedure TMyObject.B(const AObject: TMyObject);` in D7 and it still compiles with `object` and `class`

Comment: @Stuart see my edited answer. Maybe you're facing a bug, but as for me, your original question is answered. You have to narrow down the problem and if you have new questions, you're welcome back with that, but as you see, what you see is not a general failure, but something more specific to the object/record/class you have at hand.

Comment: Interesting. This scenario definitely fails on both Delphi7 and Delphi2006. I'm guessing that you must have an update version of D7 that has the bug fixed. I've edited my initial post to give a complete listing of the code that fails.

Comment: @Stuart Your code fails in D7 too. I can reproduce it. It's a simple compiler bug. You know the workaround. My answer explains why `TComplex` is the other way around.