# Error when using Power in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have the following function in my program and it is giving me an EInvalidOp (Invalid Floating Point Operation):

```
function TMyProgram.GetVal(A, B, C, D, E: double): double;

begin

  Result := A/Power((C - D)/(D - B), 1/E);

end;
```

The values of the parameters are:

A: 320.068,
B: 84.46,
C: 91.632,
D: 24.15,
E: 11

Excel gives me a result of -316.815, but Delphi is giving me an error when I execute this function.

Comment: From what I understand you can't raise raise a negative value to a non-integer power in real numbers. Ultimately you are ending up with a call like this Power(-1.11891891891892, 0.0909090909090909) which is the problem. I will wait for the maths experts to confirm this though.

Comment: But Excel does it alright.

Comment: Interesting. The docs say "for fractional exponents, base must be greater than 0". I wonder why.

Comment: If you look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Treatment_on_computers - There are issues on computers with power calculations.

Comment: That would involve getting into complex numbers, I suppose (for example, -1 ^ 0.5 is the square root of -1, which is really an imaginary number), so I get what the "docs" say, but I wonder how Excel solves this problem.

Comment: Excel is doing an absolute on the base and then negating the result. A number of online calculators do the same thing.

Comment: Python, which supports complex numbers, gives the answer as 303.9819642138474-89.2571580686281j. We're definitely into complex numbers here. Delphi has an ancient complex number implementation. There's a more modern one in the samples collection using records with methods that I believe was written by Marco Cantu.

Comment: You have to decide what answer you want. What do you want this calculation to return? Perhaps an exception is correct.

Comment: @alcalde Delphi has no support for complex numbers

Comment: @DavidHeffernan There's some support involving Variants - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.VarCmplx. There's also a sample with a bit more usable setup but I'm assuming that if it's a sample it's unsupported: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE6/en/RTL.ComplexNumbers_Sample.

Comment: @alcalde It's useless though. The perf is dire. I've got a nice Complex record with operator overloading. With good perf.

Comment: @alcalde Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074668

Answer (score -1, accepted):

-316.81520613

Thats what i get with the power2 function by Jack Lyle.

look here for full code [power2](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20026)

{** A power function from Jack Lyle. Said to be more powerful than the
    Pow function that comes with Delphi. }

```
function Power2(Base, Exponent : Double) : Double;
{ raises the base to the exponent }
  CONST
    cTiny = 1e-15;

  VAR
    Power : Double; { Value before sign correction }

  BEGIN
    Power := 0;
    { Deal with the near zero special cases }
    IF (Abs(Base) < cTiny) THEN BEGIN
      Base := 0.0;
    END; { IF }
    ... // see the link to full code

  END; { FUNCTION Pow }
```

Comment: Just a warning, that function gives the incorrect value for Power2(-1.5, 0.5) which is the square root of -1.5.

Comment: @Graymatter : have a look at the warning at the bottom end of article. **Do not use the simple power function if you expect to ever see a negative base as input.**

Comment: The way I read it, that warning is about the built in power function, not the with the supplied code.

Comment: I believe the correct answer should be a complex number.

Comment: @moskito-x You should read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Real_exponents_with_negative_bases

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : thanks for the link . I think I understand it now. This kind of math is for me the heavier material.

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit more research. The problem is raising a negative base to a fractional exponent. In your particular case you can use mathematical identity to get around it by doing the following:

```
function TMyProgram.GetVal(A, B, C, D: Double; E: Integer): double;
begin
  if Odd(E) and ((C - D)/(D - B) < 0) then
    Result := A/-Power(Abs((C - D)/(D - B)), 1/E)
  else
    Result := A/Power((C - D)/(D - B), 1/E);
end;
```

This only works when E is an odd number.

Comment: If else with an even (E) raises an exception for what is this "else" then good ?

Comment: It calculates the other options. For example where `(C - D)/(D - B)` > 0. In the case where there is an exception in the else block then there is not much we can do as the result in that case is a complex number.

Comment: if E=11 then i get the same number -316.81520613 . But may be that I've got something misunderstood . If I test with E=8 or 10 or 12 . I get `invalid Floating Point Operation`.

Comment: @moskito-x If I take -3^3 that gives me -27. The cube root of -27 is -3. That's the same as saying -27^1/3=-3. Because the number is odd we can "move" the negative outside and write it like this -(Abs(-27)^1/3). That only works when we are dealing with odd numbers because, as an example, the square root of -4 is not -2, its a complex number.

Comment: With `power2` and a even number=12. I get `-317.08500501` without an exception . Sorry I demand so ignorant, but why is that so?

Comment: @moskito-x Because the code in `power2` is incorrect. It's applying the rule in all cases where the base is negative when it should only apply it in certain cases.

Comment: You wrote `It calculates the other options. For example where (C - D)/(D - B) > 0`. On basis of the `AND` in your code the else statement is also executed if "E" is even and also `(C - D)/(D - B) < 0` !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55739/discussion-between-graymatter-and-moskito-x).

Comment: +1 this is indeed the rule that allows Excel to evaluate this